# Parse URL with CGI script

Tags: facebook, url, cgi

I am getting response from facebook API for accesstoken but can't able to parse that because no ? symbol getting in URL

Example:

http://YOUR_URL#access_token=166942940015970%7C2.sa0&expires_in=64090

I want to get the `access_token` value in CGI variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get `access_token` this way on server-side (which is probably case for `CGI`) because of `#` (hash sign).

Everything after `#` called [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and will not be passed to server. It will exist only on client-side, so you probably need to parse it's on client side or pass it to server side in other ways than regular request to this URL...

Answer (score 0):

I am getting response in this URL so i need the access_token value..can't able to get from client side..